# Overloading type cast operator, to cast to a pointer to function

Tags: c++, casting, function-pointers

I'm having some difficulty, overloading the cast to pointer to function operator of a class. In code, what I want is this:

```
typedef int(*funcptrtype)(int);

struct castable {
   operator funcptrtype() {return NULL;}
};
```

but I want to be able to do it without using the `typedef`. If you're curious, I need this, because pre-c++11 template aliases aren't available (so the `typedef` trick is not an option in templated contexts...)

I would normally expect this to work:

```
operator int(*)(int)() {return NULL;}
```

But it doesn't. The compiler (g++ 4.6.1) says:

```
error: ‘<invalid operator>’ declared as function returning a function
```

This works:

```
int (* operator()())(int){return 0;}
```

But you're actually overloading the `operator()` to return a function pointer :)

The standard says:

> The conversion-type-id shall not represent a function type nor an
>   array type

But it doesn't say function pointer type (The first code snipplet works anyway...).

Does anyone know the right syntax w/o `typedef`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755673/c-conversion-operator-for-converting-to-function-pointer

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: You should vote to close as an exact duplicate (rather than just adding the link as a comment, which on the other hand is much better than not doing it either :))

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I didn't vote because I don't know if it's an *exact* duplicate.

Comment: Looks to be exact to me.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Looks exact to me too. What I don't understand is how I've missed it.

Answer (score 3):

The grammar doesn't allow this: the type in a conversion operator declaration is a *type-specifier*, not a *type-id*. You have to use a typedef or alias; in a template context, use the usual replacement:

```
template<typename T>
struct something {
  typedef T (*type)(int);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with this is the fact that the parameter type T is not deducable anymore.