# How to define a class type conversion to a pointer to function?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I am trying to understand more Class-type conversion. I am reading C++ primer 5ed. So I've tried this code:

```
int add(int x, int y) { return x + y;}

struct Foo
{
    //operator(int(*)(int, int))(){return add;} // error
    using pfn = int(*)(int, int);
    operator pfn(){return add;} // OK
    double value = 5.45;
};

int main()
{

    cout << (int(*)(int, int))Foo()(5, 7) << endl; // why 1
    cout << ((int(*)(int, int))Foo())(5, 7) << endl; // Ok 12

    std::cout << "\nDone!\n";
}
```

- So why I cannot directly define conversion for my class using the type `int(*)(int, int)` but I can with a type alias?
- Why I get value `1` in the first statement which is erroneous and get it correct in the second statement using parenthesis?
- I get the warning from first statement: `Description Resource Path    Location Type cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast] main.cpp /MyCppProj line 31 C/C++ Problem`

Comment: The first one casts `Foo()(5, 7)` – which is 12 – to a function pointer; non-null pointers convert to `true`, which is printed as `1`.

Comment: I'm still struggling with the correct syntax for the operator. However, for a member function would look like this: `int (*getAdd())(int, int) { return add; }`: [**demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94dff61076298e38) I'm not really sure that the operator can be defined at all. I believe your alternative with `using` isn't that bad. (At least, it's much more readable.)

Comment: After having got serious doubts that it's possible at all, I googled and found: [SO: C++ Conversion operator for converting to function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6755760/7478597).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Conversion operator for converting to function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755673/c-conversion-operator-for-converting-to-function-pointer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - So why I cannot directly define conversion for my class using the type `int(*)(int, int)` but I can with a type alias?

The [grammar](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.conv.fct#nt:conversion-function-id) for the "`operator` TYPE" name of a conversion function is much more restricted than a more general declarator or *type-id*. It doesn't allow parentheses at all, only a type specifier (like a type alias name, `unsigned int`, a class name, etc.), combinations of the `*`, `&`, `&&`, `const` and `volatile` tokens, and `[[`attributes`]]`. I can't say exactly why, but complicated declarations like that are tricky to write, read, and parse. Maybe there's a potential ambiguity in some case if more were allowed, or maybe they just didn't want to require compilers to have to figure this one out.

Also, if it *were* allowed, maybe the form would be `operator int (*())(int, int);` and not `operator (int(*)(int, int))()`? Or maybe that doesn't make sense either. See? Tricky.

> - Why I get value `1` in the first statement which is erroneous and get it correct in the second statement using parenthesis?

Function call syntax has higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than C-style cast. So

```
(int(*)(int, int))Foo()(5, 7)    // (1)
(int(*)(int, int)) (Foo()(5, 7)) // (2), same as (1)
((int(*)(int, int))Foo()) (5, 7) // (3), not the same
```

Expression (1) or (2) evaluates by first creating a temporary `Foo`. It's followed by function call syntax, and `Foo` doesn't define an `operator()`, but C++ will also check if it implicitly converts to a pointer or reference to function and it does, so the `(5, 7)` does the implicit conversion and calls the resulting pointer to `add`, giving 12. This is cast to the function pointer type, which has implementation-defined results. There is no `operator<<` declared for function pointers, but there is one for `bool`, and a function pointer can implicitly convert to `bool`. Presumably the result of the strange cast was not a null pointer value, so the end result is `true`, and you see the value `1`. (If you had done `std::cout << std::boolalpha` earlier, you should see `true` or an appropriate translation instead.)

One piece of this, besides the operator precedence misunderstanding, is the dangers of a C-style cast, which can do very many different things, some not usually intended. Use `static_cast<int(*)(int,int)>(Foo())(5,7)` instead, and everything's fine. Or if we accidentally typed `static_cast<int(*)(int,int)>(Foo()(5,7))` instead, the compiler gives an error about converting from `int` to `int(*)(int,int)`, since only `reinterpret_cast` or C-style cast may do that.

> - I get the warning from first statement: `Description Resource Path    Location Type cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast] main.cpp /MyCppProj line 31 C/C++ Problem`

Even though the C-style cast forces the conversion from `int` to function pointer to be valid, the compiler is warning that `int` doesn't have enough bytes to represent a function pointer. It's assuming the `int` value earlier came from casting a function pointer to some numeric type, and this is meant to convert back, but whenever it was converted from a type large enough to `int`, the pointer value was lost.

Comment: I do really appreciate it! Clear now for me thank you so much.

Comment: I've seen some  working solution as: `(*operator int() const)(int, int){return sub;}` what do you think? It seems to me so strange! doesn't it?

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. Looks like g++ accepts it, but clang++ and MSVC reject ([compare](https://godbolt.org/z/C4ydT6)). And I don't think [\[class.conv.fct\]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.conv.fct#1) allows it.